# Extract value from string Node red

Tags: parsing, node-red

how do I extract data within some brackets?
So msg.payload = 123(ABCD)4

What function will extract ABCD from this string?

Comment: Did you try using a RegExp?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please read the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what a good question should contain, it needs to show what you've already tried and explain how it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try fiddle with the javaScript node and play with this, there are many ways to do that as well.

```js
var str =  "123(ABCD)4"
var first = str.split('(')
var second = first[1].split(')')
console.log(second[0])
```